# Task and concurrent access in Julia

Tags: concurrency, julia, ada

Task and concurrent access in Julia

I would like to implement in Julia  the management of virtual keyboards which are each associated o a dedicated task (or process,thread ...).

In Ada this is managed through the use of protected type objects for these virtual keyboards and of a task which scans the keyboard of the computer,as summarized in the following code example.

How could this be implemented in Julia ? Documentation is apparently poor on concurrent access control in Julia.

```ada
with Unchecked_Deallocation;
package Buffer is
 N : constant := 128;
 type Index is mod N;
 type Char_Array is array (Index) of Character;
 protected type Keyboard is
   entry Put (X : in Character);
   entry Get (X : out Character);
 private
   A               : Char_Array;
   In_Ptr, Out_Ptr : Index                := 0;
   Count           : Integer range 0 .. N := 0;
 end Keyboard;
 type Keyboard_Ptr is access all Keyboard;
 procedure Free is new Unchecked_Deallocation (Keyboard, Keyboard_Ptr);
end Buffer;

package body Buffer is
  protected body Keyboard is
    entry Put (X : in Character) when Count < N is
     begin
      A (In_Ptr) := X;
      In_Ptr     := In_Ptr + 1;
      Count      := Count + 1;
    end Put;
    entry Get (X : out Character) when Count > 0 is
     begin
      X       := A (Out_Ptr);
      Out_Ptr := Out_Ptr + 1;
      Count   := Count - 1;
    end Get;
 end Keyboard;
end Buffer;
```

---

```ada
task Keyboard_Handler;

task body Keyboard_Handler is
   K0        : Character;
   Available : Boolean   := False;
 --  Keyboard_Current : Keyboard_Ptr is defined at upper level
begin
 loop
    Get_Immediate (K0, Available);
    if Available and then Character'Pos (K0) /= 0 then
       Keyboard_Current.Put (K0);
    end if;        
    delay 0.06;
 end loop;
end Keyboard_Handler;
```

One first step is to show how to intercept specific keystokes (for example : arrows, w, v) and how to feed a channel with them. The following works fine on Windows to feed the main process with keyboard informations:

```
ch1 = Channel{String}(128)
function run(ch1::Channel)
while true 
  c1 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
  if c1 == 224
    c2 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
    if c2 == 72 
      put!(ch1, "KEY UP")
    elseif   c2 == 80 
      put!(ch1, "KEY DOWN")
    elseif   c2 == 77 
      put!(ch1, "KEY RIGHT")
    elseif   c2 == 75 
      put!(ch1, "KEY LEFT")
    elseif   c2 == 81 
      put!(ch1, "ALT KEY DOWN")
    elseif   c2 == 73 
      put!(ch1, "ALT KEY UP")
    end
 elseif c1 == Int32('w')
   put!(ch1, "w")
 elseif c1 == Int32('v')  
   put!(ch1, "v")
 end
end
end
buffer = Channel(run)
for x in buffer
   println(x)
end
```

Now I would like to feed a task of my choice with the keyboard inputs. May be with something like :

```
using Distributed
addprocs(3)

function tache1(ch::Channel)
 for x in ch
   println("TACHE 1 :",x)
 end
end

function tache2(ch::Channel)
 for x in ch
   println("TACHE 2 :",x)
 end
end

buffer1 = Channel(tache1)
buffer2 = Channel(tache2)

ch1 = buffer1

function run()
 while true 
  c1 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
  if c1 == 224
   c2 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
   if c2 == 72 
     put!(ch1, "KEY UP")
   elseif   c2 == 80 
     put!(ch1, "KEY DOWN")
   elseif   c2 == 77 
     put!(ch1, "KEY RIGHT")
   elseif   c2 == 75 
     put!(ch1, "KEY LEFT")
   elseif   c2 == 81 
     put!(ch1, "ALT KEY DOWN")
   elseif   c2 == 73 
     put!(ch1, "ALT KEY UP")
   end
   elseif c1 == Int32('w')
    ch1 = Channel(tache1)
   elseif c1 == Int32('v')
    ch1 = Channel(tache2)    
   end
  end
end

f = @spawnat 1 run()

function t1()
  for x in buffer1
    println("11111 ",x)
  end
end

function t2()
  for x in buffer2
    println("22222 ",x)
  end
end

h1 = @spawnat 2 t1()
h2 = @spawnat 3 t2()

for x in buffer1
  println(x)
end
```

But it does not work !  May be Julia is not able to do what Ada can do quite easily ... ?? Or more probably I have a very bad understanding of the multitask aspects of Julia.

Comment: What have you tried in Julia?  Have you looked at Julia's documentation for [Multithreading](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/index.html) and [Parallel Computing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/)?

Comment: The only subject I have found in Julia documentation which seems close to Ada protected objects is "Shared Arrays" but I don't see how to use it for my quite simple purpose.

Comment: I see also in the documentation that Channels can be quite useful to pass data between running tasks, particularly those involving I/O operations. I should have a look to that ...

Comment: I think that Channels would work well. Are you expecting to intercept unbuffered keyboard input here? Unbuffered keystroke input from the keyboard is very OS specific in general, and Julia does not have much support for that type of input outside of frameworks like Gtk.jl which uses the Gtk library.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added some code to the question, so I added the code here. 
The original example is below this.

```
# This works and perhaps is what you wanted to do? 
# I am unsure of some of the tasks you set up in the question's code.


CHAN1 = Channel{String}(0)
CHAN2 = Channel{String}(0)

function tache1()
    while true
        x = take!(CHAN1)
        println("TACHE 1 :", x)
    end
end

function tache2()
    while true
        x = take!(CHAN2)
        println("TACHE 2 :", x)
    end
end

function run()
    try
    println("Esc to exit.")
    chan = CHAN1
    while true 
        c1 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
        if c1 == 224
            c2 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
            if c2 == 72 
                put!(chan, "KEY UP")
            elseif   c2 == 80 
                put!(chan, "KEY DOWN")
            elseif   c2 == 77 
                put!(chan, "KEY RIGHT")
            elseif   c2 == 75 
                put!(chan, "KEY LEFT")
            elseif   c2 == 81 
                put!(chan, "ALT KEY DOWN")
            elseif   c2 == 73 
                put!(chan, "ALT KEY UP")
            end
        elseif c1 == Int32('w')
            chan = CHAN1
        elseif c1 == Int32('v')
            chan = CHAN2
        elseif(c1 == 27)
            close(CHAN1)
            close(CHAN2)
            exit(0)
        else
            println(Char(c1))
        end
    end
    catch y
        println("Exception caught: ", y)
        exit(1)
    end
end

@async run()
@async tache1()
@async tache2()

while true 
    sleep(0.05) 
end
```

## CUT ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is an example (Julia 1.0) of using the Gtk library to intercept keystrokes in 3 different windows. You could use the Channel functions with Windows C calls to _getch as well.

```
#(note: revised to show Channel usage)

using Gtk.ShortNames

function keypresswindow(chan)

    # This code creates  the Gtk widgets on the screen.
    txt = "Type Y or N"
    win = Window("Keypress Test", 250, 30) |> (Frame() |> 
          ((vbox = Box(:v)) |> (lab  = Label(txt))))

    # this is the keystroke processing code, a function and a callback for the function.
    function keycall(w, event)
        ch = Char(event.keyval)
        put!(chan, ch)
        set_gtk_property!(lab,:label, ch in('n','N','y','Y') ? "You hit the $ch key." : txt)
    end
    Gtk.signal_connect(keycall, win, "key-press-event")

    # this code sets up a proper exit when the widow is closed.
    c = Condition()
    endit(w) = notify(c)
    Gtk.signal_connect(endit, win, :destroy)
    Gtk.showall(win)
    wait(c) 
end

function reader(chan)
    while true
        try 
            c = take!(chan)
            print(c)
        catch
            return
        end
    end
end

function inputwindows(chan, numwindows)
    @async reader(chan)
    println("starting input windows")
    @sync(
    for i in 1:numwindows
        @async keypresswindow(chan)
    end
    )
    println("finished")
end

const chan = Channel(1020)
inputwindows(chan, 3)
```

Comment: I think it is simpler to import the system C function which intercept, eventually through repetition, the keystroke as a sequence of integer. For Windows : ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,()).

Comment: I have shown how to use C function import to intercept keystrokes in an addition to my question text.

Comment: The last solution with getch() answers my question using channels which in addition to keyboard control can be use to establish communication between Tbasks. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the solution to my question does not need Channel. The simple fact that Tasks in Julia are mere coroutines, guarantes that there will be no confict on keyboard access. On Windows platform a demonstration of a solution for 2 Tasks chosen and driven through keyboard interaction is :

```
function run1()
  while true 
    c1 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
    if c1 == 224
       c2 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
       if c2 == 72 
          println("KEY UP1")
       elseif   c2 == 80 
          println("KEY DOWN1")
       elseif   c2 == 77 
          println("KEY RIGHT1")
       elseif   c2 == 75 
         println("KEY LEFT1")
       elseif   c2 == 81 
         println("ALT KEY DOWN1")
       elseif   c2 == 73 
         println("ALT KEY UP1")
      end
    elseif c1 == Int32('w')
      yieldto(tb)
    end
   end
end

function run2()
   while true 
     c1 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
     if c1 == 224
        c2 =  ccall((:_getch, "msvcrt.dll "), Int32,())
        if c2 == 72 
          println("KEY UP2")
        elseif   c2 == 80 
          println("KEY DOWN2")
        elseif   c2 == 77 
          println("KEY RIGHT2")
        elseif   c2 == 75 
          println("KEY LEFT2")
        elseif   c2 == 81 
          println("ALT KEY DOWN2")
        elseif   c2 == 73 
          println("ALT KEY UP2")
        end
    elseif c1 == Int32('w')
      yieldto(ta)
    end
  end
end

ta = Task(run1)

tb = Task(run2)

yieldto(tb)
```